# EXC_BREAKPOINT - Troubled line known but not understandable

Tags: swift, exception, swift3

I get this below recorder over crashlytics:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000100118c5c
```

With this being last line of the call stack:

```
FPRequest.asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest (FPRequest.swift:116)
```

Which is last line of this block:

```
    switch self {
    case .authenticate, .renewAuth:
        mutableURLRequest.setValue(self.oAuthUserHeader, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    case .getGroups, .getJobs, .getServices, .submitTimesheet, .getStaffId, .getTasks, .getTimesheets, .deleteTimesheet, .completeTask, .beginTask:
        mutableURLRequest.setValue("Bearer \(FPRequest.oAuthToken!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

But I do not get what can get wrong here. mutableURLRequest is non-optional var.  Is that really an exception happening here?

Comment: It seems that you are using `NSMutableURLRequest`. Don't do that in Swift 3. There is a native struct `URLRequest` which is mutable with the `var` keyword.

Comment: Make sure `FPRequest.oAuthToken!` is not `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for an idea. Though I'd expect null pointer exception in this case.

Comment: Well, the fantasy of Swift creators is unlimited: 

EXC_BREAKPOINT (Trace Trap)
Much like “EXC_CRASH”, it is more like to work with debugger and caught during your testing phase.

When using Swift, this exception will be thrown at runtime if:

a non-optional type with a nil value
a failed forced type conversion